# Private queue NSManagedObjectContext save end in infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, core-data

I have a main `NSManagedObjectContext` object on main thread. And a private queue `NSManagedObjectContext` to do quick `NSManagedObject` operation without affecting the main thread.

The code for init this private queue `NSManagedObjectContext` is below:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tempContext.parentContext = _context;
    NSLog(@"LALALA");
    [tempContext performBlock:^{
    //do some work
    NSError *error;
        if([tempContext hasChanges]){
            [tempContext save:&error];
        }

        [_appDelegate saveMainContextWithCompletion:^{
         // do some work
        }];
    }];
```

The app freezes at `[tempContext save&error]`, I use Instrument to see what's going on. It shows there is no memory leak, but I see it infinitely malloc `CFString` in memory.

Can someone tell me why this bug happens?

Comment: what kind of work you are doing in perform block?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman just grab some `NSManagedObject` from `tempContext` and assign some attributes new values and then save. By the way, I am using this with `NSfetchedResultsController` and `UITableView`.

Comment: Hi Arthur. I've downvoted, as two answers came in on the same day you asked this, and one remains unresponded to, and neither were voted on. Please do respond to people who give their time and effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As tempContext is not in main thread, wrap the code in this:

```
if (tempContext != nil) {
    [tempContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([tempContext hasChanges] && ![tempContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@\n UserInfo: %@\n", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            //No error
        }
    }];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, Rashad. it doesn't work. The `[tempContext save:&error]` method never returns. It's running infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably whatever you are doing in your app delegate and the saveMainContextWithCompletion method. You are probably inadvertently causing your background thread and the main thread to keep posting blocks to each other for saves and merges.

Instead of doing this you should let the background context finish saving and rely on the managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification to respond to those changes on the main thread.

Finally since you set up the parent context relationship the changes you make in your background context should propagate for you. You shouldn't need to explicitly save both contexts.